# Multi Sheet Excel Calculations with Drop down

Tags: excel-2010

I have been trying this all day now, and I am about ready to give up and write a .net program...

My current layout is as follows:

Sheet 1 (Materials in inventory)

- Material Name
- Original Cost

Sheet 2 (current project)

- Material Name (data validation drop-down)
- % used
- Cost (calculated from % used * sheet1's original cost)

I would think that it would be easy to find the "original cost" cell from sheet2 based on the drop down menu, but I cant figure it out for the life of me. I do have the data validation working, but I cant seem to access the "original cost" cell based on the data validation drop-down.

What kind of formula would I need to use to access the information in sheet1 based on the drop-down menu in sheet 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to use a Vlookup to gather the original costs from sheet one based on the value selected in the dropdown.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but with your suggestion I found a website that walked me through how to create this formula `INDEX(Materials!A1:B30,MATCH(A3,Materials!A:A,0),2)*(C3/100)`